# How can I remove a parent with a certain child inside of it (media queries)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having some trouble finding a solution to this.

I have a class called `.mainCont` which I use for each main body section.

The problem I am having is when the site switches to the responsive design I can hide the content inside of the parent but I am left with an empty rectangle because I am unable to hide the parent.

If I hide the parent then everything will hide and if I hide the child the parent will stay empty.

(I do not want to use any script for this sadly, it has to be css/media queries.)

Here is the html,

```
<div class="mainCont sideCont">
    <div class="gridBox"></div><!--
    --><div class="gridBox right"></div><!--
    --><div class="gridBox bottom"></div><!--
    --><div class="gridBox right bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I need to hide `.gridBox` but I can not hide all instances of `.mainCont` since other elements of the page use this.

Is there a selector I can use? I tried this,

```
.gridBox:parent {
   display: none;
}
```

Which did not seem to work, found on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

The only other option I can think of is giving the container a unique id but I would rather not have to. Any ideas?

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XqKW4/1/) to see how the structure is. (Some reason the fiddle will not display my `.gridBox` how it should but It must be related to the other missing html.)

Here is the [Live Site](http://chatfielddrilling.com/Chatfield%20V2/edrill.php) to see how they are suppose to look but the related code is isolated in that fiddle.

Comment: you want to hide the inner `.gridBox`? or you want to hide the first `.gridBox`?

Comment: If you want to hide the first `.gridBox`, have you tried `.gridBox:first-child {display: none;}`?

Comment: I want to hide them all plus their parent. I can't just do display none to the class .mainCont because that is used more then just there.

Comment: You want to hide just the instance of `.mainCont` that contains `.gridBox`, right? You're correct in that there are no parent selectors in CSS.

Comment: If you have access to the HTML, I suggest adding a class to each that needs to be hidden (in this case the parent) when in a certain media querie, example: `hideInResponsive` and then target that class for the `display: none`

Comment: @jackJoe, that's what he has now. You may have misunderstood the crux of the question.

Comment: @jackJoe refer to the two links I added to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Considering that `.mainCont` might contain content not inside an instance of `.gridBox.`, you're almost certainly going to need scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say from your question what's left behind when all instances of `.gridBox` disappear from their parent `.mainCont` element, but the solution would be to put all of your styles on child elements, so that when they're gone, `.mainCont` has no styles and no size. It will still be in the DOM, but it won't be visible.

I can offer more help if you create a demo with your CSS. http://jsfiddle.net

---

In light of further information, you'll almost certainly need scripting. Put this anywhere:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    var myEls = $('.mainCont').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('.gridBox').length === 0;
    });
    $(myEls).hide();

}):
</script>
```

You'll need to wrap it in a window.resize function, of course.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XqKW4/3

Comment: I just added a fiddle and the live site at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I also have this set up on pretty much every page so I need something to select `.mainCont` only if it is containing `.gridBox`.

Comment: Ah. You didn't indicate initially that `.mainCont` might contain content not inside an instance of `.gridBox`. That makes my answer not viable.

Comment: I do apologize for the confusion, do you have any ideas? Is adding a unique id to this div the only option I have besides using a script?

Comment: You have jQuery loaded in your page. Use it. :-) See my updated answer.

Comment: Oops. I had my logic back-asswards. Updated.

Comment: This works great! I don't have to worry about this effecting my load time much on a mobile device do I? (on previous mobile designs, jQuery animate seemed to add load time. This does seem like a very small function though.)

Comment: Not if jQuery is already loading for mobile. As you said, it's pretty tiny. Good luck.